# How would you store geo location data with timestamp information?

Tags: mongodb

I want to store the users' location at a certain timestamp and some meta data (like speed, etc.) in mongodb. (Could become a large data set)
The goal is to display the data as a heatmap on Google Maps. The user can choose which time frame of data he wants to see on the map, so I would need to query for the location AND the time.

I know there is GeoJSON, which you can use to query for location constraints, but how would you add the time, especially in terms of query performance?

Comment: Time is part of the `ObjectId`. See [ObjectId.getTimestamp()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.getTimestamp/). You can also add a Time object into the document with the GeoJSON.

Comment: That's a really good idea, although the data is coming from a device before it's actually stored in the db. So the timestamp would != creation time. I didn't find anything to initialize an ObjectID with a date unfortunately.